# Adding WMS layer on QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

I am trying to add WMS layer on QGIS. It has been added but it says `'Protocol "" is unknown'`.

The URL I am using are:
https://data.opendevelopmentmekong.net/geoserver/ODCambodia/Forest_cover_2009/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&layers=ODCambodia%3AForest_cover_2009

https://data.opendevelopmentmekong.net/geoserver/ODCambodia/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities

How can I display it?

Comment: When you specify a geoserver WMS in QGIS use only the URL up to and including the? Don't include any request parameters

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be an error on the Geoserver version they are using

```
https://data.opendevelopmentmekong.net/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0

> This page contains the following errors: error on line 5910 at column
> 17: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document Below is
> a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

However the links in the catalog are listed
https://data.opendevelopmentmekong.net/dataset/forest-cover-in-cambodia-2015-2017?type=dataset
do not have the forest cover for 2009

They do for 2015

```
https://data.opendevelopmentmekong.net/geoserver/ODCambodia/Cambodia_forest_cover_2015/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&layers=ODCambodia%3ACambodia_forest_cover_2015
```

and that will load in QGIS
when dpi mode is changed in to Geoserver.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your answer! It worked! I found the data for other years too. But it still has "Protocol "" is unknown" below the new layer. I'm not sure if it will cause trouble. Thank you so much!!! (:

Comment: The issues in the capabilities response are out of bounds values in the `EX_GeographicBoundingBox` sections.   For example 'cvc-type.3.1.3: The value `1625604.875' of element 'northBoundLatitude' is not valid.`